# I have issue with my implementation Google map

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-maps-api-3

I have this code :

````
class MapActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

    lateinit var map: GoogleMap
    lateinit var fusedlocation: FusedLocationProviderClient
    lateinit var lastlocation: Location
    private val RequestCode = 10


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity)


        val mapfragment: SupportMapFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapfragment.getMapAsync(this)


    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {


        map = googleMap

        map.uiSettings.isZoomControlsEnabled = true

        fusedlocation = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
            fusedlocation.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener(this) { location ->

                lastlocation = location

                if (location != null) {


                    val home = LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)

                    map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().title("Home").position(home))
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(home, 16f))

                    btn_submit.setOnClickListener {




                        val geo = Geocoder(this , Locale.getDefault())
                        val address : List<Address>
                        address = geo.getFromLocation(location.latitude , location.longitude , 1)


                        yourlocation.text = address[0].adminArea
                        yourlocation.text = address[0].countryCode
                        yourlocation.text = address[0].countryName
                        yourlocation.text = address[0].featureName
                        yourlocation.text = address[0].locality

                    }

                } else {

                    val home = LatLng(31.363011, 48.643506)
                    map.addMarker(MarkerOptions().title("Home").position(home))
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(home, 16f))
                    Toast.makeText(this, "the Location not found ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

            }

        } else {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                    RequestCode
                )

            }

        }
    }


override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    permissions: Array<out String>,
    grantResults: IntArray
) {

    when (requestCode) {

        RequestCode -> if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //permission granted no need to do anything
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "دسترسی به ویژگی مکان یابی داده نشد .", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()

        }


    }

}


}```
````

The first of all thank's for helping me and see my code .

the main issue is when i want to convert the location into a text with Geocoder it's give me this error : grpc failed
what is wrong with my code ?
i use api key in my manifest . and also add the google service and google location in my gradle .

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get current location with AVD, it will show Google company in US and you won't get your desired response.